# Conllevar, its meaning in this sentence

Tags: definiciones, significado

I'm reading a book, and it says

> «La felicidad conlleva la intimidad con la belleza(...)»

On wordreference, conllevar means *«Implicar, traer como consecuencia, acarrear»*, however if I substitute in the original sentence, any of the supposed meanings, then I think something is lost. I get the feeling that, in this sentence, conllevar is more like 'bring' or something similar, that may give a feeling simultaneity, instead of cause and effect.

Am I wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the right track. The problem is that that sentence has quite an abstract meaning. Just with that sentence (and no context) is difficult for me too (native Spanish speaker) to grab the meaning, implications, etc. since it doesn't make *that much sense* by itself. I actually disagree on that statement. It almost looks like something that came out of one of those *fortune cookies* that don't really tell you your fortune, just a random statement.

> Happiness implies intimacy with beauty.

I don't know if it makes sense to you or if it does in the context of that book?

You could play with some synonyms of *conllevar*, thought, to get

> La felicidad abarca la intimidad con la belleza.
>
> La felicidad supone la intimidad con la belleza.
>
> La felicidad trae la intimidad con la belleza.

All of them would keep having that abstract meaning, so you should see what works given you context.

Hope that it helps.

Edit: Encontré la cita (o un uso similar) en un libro de [Tomás de Aquino](http://books.google.com/books?id=uhgQJnpDKnIC&pg=PA98&lpg=PA98&dq=La+felicidad+conlleva+la+intimidad+con+la+belleza&source=bl&ots=Qx3R7FOJxL&sig=wC8Fwq_SVV220CogQl7UsI1zckU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fEY8VJG2NKOSsQTKyoC4DA&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=La%20felicidad%20conlleva%20la%20intimidad%20con%20la%20belleza&f=false)

Es curioso que no explica bien porqué afirma que la felicidad implica o va de la mano con la intimidad con la belleza. Hago la misma lectura de la frase: Si has encontrado la felicidad, tienes *intimidad con la belleza*. Ahora, lo que no entiendo es el sentido de esto último, y no creo que tenga nada que ver con el uso de la palabra *conllevar*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll wait a bit more to see if there will be another answer. until then +1

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. I think I found your reference (edited my answer. I know you won't have trouble with Spanish, but let me know if you want me to clarify in English). I don't understand the statement either. "Implies" would work for a translation of _conllevar_, I I still don't get what the writer is trying to explain. Sorry, I think is all I can do.

Comment: =D You're right, it's from that book. :) 
At this point, where the sentence is written, the author has yet to explain the reasoning behind that sentence. I'm really enjoying the book.If you're curious about it,try reading it. =)  Many thanks for the help.

Comment: I think I actually must have read something from him back at school for my _Filosofía_ and/or _Religión_ classes. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that this sentence wouldnt have been used by a native Spanish speaker. It has probably been a traduction error.

If you want to use the word conllevar in that sentence, it is necessary to avoid the word "la".

Ser feliz conlleva intimidad con la belleza.

And now means exactly the same as implica alltough the sentence is still a bit extrange. The complete sentence would also include a verb that could be estar o tener, but in spanish can be omitted.

Comment: La cita parece ser de Tomás de Aquino. No me parece un error de traducción. Creo que tampoco terminas de entender la pregunta. El usuario no quiere simplemente usar _conllevar_ en esa frase, si no comprender el significado de la misma.

Comment: Sí he entendido la pregunta, lo que pasa es que no puedo decirle el significado concreto de una palabra en una frase en una palabra si la frase no es correcta. Ya se que gramaticalmente es correcta, pero no tiene sentido. Cuando algo conlleva algo es necesario que lo cause (el dolor conlleva odio) o que lo relacione (estar guapa conlleva horas de trabajo), pero en ningún caso añades el determinante (al menos en España)

Comment: Perdón, justo porque no tiene sentido no es correcta gramaticalmente.